# What is this error in swift: "signal SIGABRT"

Tags: swift

I've tried all the solution, though I think it's related to segue.
this is the message for the error:

UserLoginAndRegistration[34910:1717023] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'LoginView''

Answer (score 0):

The error message **has no segue with identifier 'LoginView'** is pretty clear.

Make sure that

- A segue is designed in Interface Builder for the `Receiver` controller and
- `LoginView` is written into the `Identifier` field of the segue.